# Calculate filterd Items

Tags: 2010, list, workflow

For the given below list 1 I would like to calculate the total price of each category per store. So that list 2 can display that Store1 has a total of $75 in Clothing, Store2 has a total of $65 in Clothing, etc. I am kind of at a loss on how make a workflow that will search through the data and calculate the items in a category.

List 1:

```
ID    Item    Category    Store    Price
1     Pants   Clothing    Store1   $75
2     Apple   Produce     Store1   $1
3     Socks   Clothing    Store2   $5
4     TV      Electr      Store1   $200
5     Pants   Clothing    Store2   $60
```

List 2:

```
ID    Category    Store    Price
1     Clothing    Store1   $75
2     Clothing    Store2   $65
3     Produce     Store1   $1
4     Electr      Store1   $200
```

Edit: I should note that I would like it recalulated each time an item in list 1 is added or edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James,

You should be able to use Group By for category and store and then sum the price (under Totals) to get the desired result.

Jim

James...this might work for you.

Grouping and Calculate Totals from One SharePoint List to Another

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687644/Grouping-and-Calculate-Totals-f

Comment: I thought of this but I need the value in a another list. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Personally, I'd do it in an application page. However, this option of using a workflow on the first list might work too. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50707/calculate-sum-of-column-and-use-in-another-lists-column-calculation